# Make a class implement Serilaizable interface dynamically?

Tags: java, reflection, interface, implements

I have many classes (50+) in a `jar` file without source code

I want to make them all implement `java.io.Serializable` **interface** so they could be saved to memcached.

I guess if java `reflection` or `dynamic proxy` can do it for me,that is to say ,

I dynamically load these classes , and then ,I dynamically make them implement java.io.Serializable interface .Any one could give me some suggestions?

Comment: My way (with gson library): convert object to json string, put to memcached. Get from memcached as json string, parse again to object.

Comment: implemeting Serializable changes the way the byte code is generated at compile time. You need the source code.

Answer (score -1):

One way of doing this is by using `java.lang.reflect.Proxy` in Java. You could read more about this [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/poonam/entry/how_to_implement_an_interface)